# Why are my variables being referenced by other functions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a really weird thing happening.  I have a script that selects between 4 different waves.  These waves have their own properties.  However, sometimes the properties from one wave will be used on a different wave.

The code is below.  As you can see there are four different types of waves.  The Debug will state Wave1 or Wave2.  It will also update all of the variables in the editor, however what is actually being seen may be the Instantiations from Wave 3 and the variables from Wave4, but the debug will say Wave 1.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

```
 void Start() {
    waveActive = false;
    dropheight = 100;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(waveActive == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine(SelectWave());
    }
}

IEnumerator SelectWave()
{
    waveActive = true;
    float val = Random.value;
    if(val <= .25)
    {
        InvokeRepeating("Wave1", delay, delay);
    }
    if (val > .25 && val <= .50)
    {
       InvokeRepeating("Wave2", delay, delay);
    }
    if (val > .5 && val <= .75)
    {
        InvokeRepeating("Wave3", delay, delay);
    }
    if (val > .75)
    {
        InvokeRepeating("Wave4", delay, delay);
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(20f,30f));
    CancelInvoke();
    waveActive = false; 
}

void Wave1()
{
    Debug.Log("Wave1");
    delay = .5f;
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop1, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop2, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop3, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);

}
void Wave2()
{
    Debug.Log("Wave2");
    delay = 1f;

    Instantiate(largeFlame, new Vector3(drop1, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(largeFlame, new Vector3(drop2, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(largeFlame, new Vector3(drop3, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);

}
void Wave3()
{
    Debug.Log("Wave3");
    delay = 4f;

    Instantiate(mediumFlame, new Vector3(drop1, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(mediumFlame, new Vector3(drop2, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(mediumFlame, new Vector3(drop3, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);

}
void Wave4()
{
    Debug.Log("Wave4");
    delay = .5f;


    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop1 - dropChange, dropHeight + dropChange, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop1, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop1 + dropChange, dropHeight + dropChange, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop2 - dropChange, dropHeight + dropChange, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop2, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop2 + dropChange, dropHeight + dropChange, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop3 - dropChange, dropHeight + dropChange, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop3, dropHeight, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(smallFlame, new Vector3(drop3 + dropChange, dropHeight + dropChange, 0), Quaternion.identity);

}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem: Instantiate everywhere! Please look into object pooling. That's just too much.

Comment: I will look into this.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think Unity's hideous background processes get messed up when you use Invoke in Coroutine. Thing is - Coroutine creates its own thread and probably, just saying, invoking stuff from background thread to main thread leads to your problem (probably). Try using a timer instead of coroutine, or option 2: make Wave() functions coroutines as well so you won't have to invoke them. Life works in mysterious ways...

Comment: hi Nika. there ARE NO "background processes" in Unity.  it is absolutely single threaded.

Comment: you almost certainly should NOT use Update() here, Tim.  the code as presented is very strange - please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to have a random wave run for 20 seconds and at the end of that time switch to a new wave.